# changing the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

Could anyone helps me in the following.

I need to show the 3 images in a image box control of asp.net.
The images should shown for 30 seconds and those should be one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about `Javascript` than `C#` / `ASP.NET`.

There are several ways to create an `Image Slideshow`:

1. Using pure `JavaScript`:

   Create a function to load next image and use `SetInterval()` function to activate that function after a specific time
2. Using `JQuery` plugins like [`Cycle`](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

---

Pure `JavaScript` Example:

```
function changeImage() {
    // ...
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "fileNameForTheNextImage";
    document["YourIMGTagID"].src = img.src;
}

// Then in your document load, after DOM Ready:

setInterval("changeImage()", 30000);
```

Comment: C# `ImageBox` controls will be sent to the browser as `img` tags. All you need to do is to define a static ID for the `ImageBox` control and use `javascript` to change that image after a period of time.

Comment: It's `setInterval` with lowercase `s`; additionally you shouldn't pass a string to this function.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, it is quite possible to pass a string to this function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think its better for you to create some javascript for easy reading and call it from code behind using RegisterStartupScript.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // called every n milisecond
        function changeImage(imgID, imageList) {
            if (typeof (this.currentImageCounter) == "undefined") {
                // init counter when necessary
                this.currentImageCounter = 0;
            } else {
                // increment counter between 0 to image array length

                this.currentImageCounter = (++this.currentImageCounter) % imageList.length;
            }

            // display image based on current image counter
            document.getElementById(imgID).src = imageList[this.currentImageCounter];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Image ID="imgSlideShow" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

note: make sure you put ClientIDMode="static", otherwise javascript won't recognized your image control.

and then call it from code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    imgSlideShow.ImageUrl = "../chimg/1-P.png"

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String), "scChangeImage", _
        "setInterval(""changeImage('imgSlideShow', " & _
        "new Array('../chimg/1-i.png','../chimg/2-i.png','../chimg/3-i.PNG'))"",2000);", True)

End Sub
```

You can also call RegisterStartupScript using C# if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can best do this with `jQuery` and `CSS`.

See for example [`Easy Jquery Auto Image Rotator`](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html) and [`Create an Image Rotator with Description (CSS/jQuery)`](http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/) or Google `JQuery Image Rotator`.